# Get From specific ID to Last

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am learning mysql and having a small issue .

I am trying to get data from one specific ID in my table to the last element.

- I'm using Laravel & eloquent but not necessary.

This is what i'm currently using :

```
$b = TableClass::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(100)->get()->reverse();
```

This basically takes the last element and 100 rows before it and then put them in order.

```
if last_id 515 and required_id = 419
```

What is the best query to get all rows from 419 to 515 in order.

**Eloquent is preferred but i can also use Direct queries.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to their guide, this is what you want:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

From 419 to last:

```
$b = TableClass::orderBy('id','asc')->where('id', '>=', 419)->get();
```

Which in query is similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id >= 419 ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks . However i don't know the id of the last element . It was just an example

Comment: @Sam.tuver 515-100 is not 419 was that a typo? You could just use `take` like in your example.

Comment: no , it was just an example . I was taking 100 element and using a for loop to get the id i wanted . Not the best way . i need to get from id e.g : 41 to last row